# yum install dependency problem

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, dependencies, software-updates

I want install `ansible` on server without internet and I have this error :

```
Error: Package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-60.el7.x86_64 (@local-repo)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-60.el7
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-60.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-60.el7
           Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64 (local-repo)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
Error: Package: 1:openssl-perl-1.0.1e-60.el7.x86_64 (@local-repo)
           Requires: openssl(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-60.el7
           Removing: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-60.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               openssl(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-60.el7
           Updated By: 1:openssl-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64 (local-repo)
               openssl(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-12.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i have `openssl-1.0.1e-60.el7.x86_64` and `openssl-libs-1.0.1e-60.el7.x86_64` in my local repository but i can't update .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `yum` isn't too smart. You are trying to install `openssl-devel-1.0.1e-60` so `yum` detects that he also needs to install `openssl-libs`. He detects that a newer version of `openssl-libs` can be installed, but that conflicts with `openssl-devel-1.0.1e-60`...

There are two possible solutions:

- make sure `openssl-devel-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64` is available in your local repositories
- force `yum` to install the older `openssl-libs` package: `yum install openssl-devel-1.0.1e-60 openssl-libs-1.0.1e-60 openssl-1.0.1e-60`